# Can't unmute ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my laptop. Recently I installed a music recording and mixing software called kxstudio. Since then my system is permanently muted. I can't increase the volume using the keyboard. When I try increasing system volume from Sound Settings it reverts back to zero immediately after I close the window. The mute option under the sound icon in the system tray is permanently ticked.

I uninstalled kxstudio but that hasn't seemed to have helped. Is there a way to revert back to a previous state? Or any alternative solution to get sound back on my system?

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with the sound on my laptop too. 
Installing the [gnome alsa mixer](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/sound/gnome-alsamixer) helped - it gives you a graphical interface with more control than the standard system settings. 
Although often you have to juggle between the two to get things to work.

Just find your speakers in the app and unmute them.

Comment: the link is outdated